# Heap space problems when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, heap-memory, executorservice

I am quite new at using Java. So, maybe my question will be very basic. I apologise in advance for this.

I need to perform many costly repetitive calculations (mainly eigenvalue decomposition and multiplying huge matrices). As all repetitions are independent, I decided to make them concurrently. Thus, I am using ExecutorService for this.

My problem is that the threads run out of memory, even if I launch the job using -Xms3000m -Xmx3000m, or I use newSingleThreadExecutor(). I thought that I had a memory leak, but the serial version of my code runs finely with just 80m of heap space. More weirdly (at least for me), when I use newFixedThreadPool(), after the first threads (~15) crashed, the calculation works and the heap used starts descending (profiled using NetBeans).

I also tried executor.execute() and executor.submit() without difference.

I post below the code I am using:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);       

    double totalMaximumLikelihood = 0.0;
    Iterator iterator1 = myAlignment.columnsMap.keySet().iterator();
    while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        boolean pairToBeCalculated = false;
        ArrayList<String> myKey1 = (ArrayList) iterator1.next();

        Iterator iterator2 = myAlignment.columnsMap.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            ArrayList myKey2 = (ArrayList) iterator2.next();

            if (pairToBeCalculated == true) {

                Runnable worker = new MySingleCoevolutionRunnable(myKnotsInNewickTree, queryNode, myAlignment, myMeanPosteriorRates, myKey1, myKey2);
                //executor.submit(worker);
                executor.execute(worker);

            } else if (myKey1.equals(myKey2)) {
                pairToBeCalculated = true;
            }
        }

    }
    executor.shutdown();
```

EDIT: It seems that I was making a newbie error. When the threads were scheduled, the constructor of the runnable was creating a model for each one, requiring a huge amount of memory. After some crashes, there was enough memory for running the rest of scheduled threads.

Comment: How many such `worker` objects are created?  If they are very large, and there isn't enough memory to keep them in the unbounded backing queue of the `ExecutorService`, you may run out of memory. `-Xms3000m -Xmx3000m`: 64-bit JVM (32-bit user process allocation is much less than 2^32).  Could you see threads being reused after your  worker finishes?